# Does integral of f(x) = the integral of conjugate of f(x)?

Tags: calculus

$$\int f(x) = \int \overline f(x)$$

Is the above statement true?

Comment: No, $\int \overline f\,dx=\overline{\int f\,dx}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since integration on complex functions is defined by
$$\int f(z) \mathrm dz := \int \Re(f(z)) \mathrm dz + i \int\Im (f(z))\mathrm dz$$
You can quickly see
$$\int \bar f(z) \mathrm dz = \int\Re(\bar f(z)) \mathrm dz + i \int \Im(\bar f(z)) \mathrm dz = \int\Re(f(z)) \mathrm dz + i \int -\Im (f(z)) \mathrm dz \\
= \int \Re(f(z)) \mathrm dz -i\int\Im(f(z)) \mathrm dz = \overline{\int f(z) \mathrm dz}$$